# How to access the saved file path downloaded from URl

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have used this process to download file from the link. Now i want the file path to access this video and play with APPlayer:

```
 @IBAction func btnplayClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    let videoImageUrl = "https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/samplecode/avfoundationMedia/AVFoundationQueuePlayer_HLS2/master.m3u8"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                let url = NSURL(string: videoImageUrl);
                let urlData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!);
                if(urlData != nil)
                {
                    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0];
                    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/video.mp4";
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        urlData?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true);
                        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                        }) { completed, error in
                            if completed {
                                print("Video is saved!")
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: ".mp4")
                                        {
                                            let apath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                                            let video = AVPlayer(URL: apath)
                                            let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
                                            videoPlayer.player = video
                                           self.presentViewController(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
                                                video.play()
                                            })
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
   })
}
```

Video is downloaded and i can see it on gallery.But AVPlayer does not play the video..What am i doing wrong here..?

Comment: Here you are wrong NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: ".mp4") , You are telling AVPlayer to load a video file from NSBundle i.e assets not from document directory where video is stored

Comment: can you tell me how can i access this one..?please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS iOS greek Greek told you are accessing wrong path,you can do it with this approach:

```
if completed {


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                        // Call UI related operations
let apath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
let video = AVPlayer(URL: apath)
let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
 videoPlayer.player = video
self.presentViewController(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
 video.play()
 })
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks  i was stucked in dispatch_async

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to load the `AVPlayer` directly from the cached path? doing so:

```
if completed {
    let video = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    videoPlayer.player = video
    self.presentViewController(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
        video.play()
    })
}
```